# MeiliSearch with Rust SDK search query with limit

Tags: rust, meilisearch

I am trying to search for documents by a search value and also set a limit. The default limit set by the SDK is 20 and I would like to increase it a little bit. With a standard curl this is easy but I struggle to implement the same functionality with the Rust SDK for MeiliSearch.

```
curl \
  'http://localhost:7700/indexes/movies/search' \
  --data '{ "q": "american","limit":55 }'
```

the docs (https://docs.meilisearch.com/references/documents.html#get-documents) offer this solution but I don't know how to send a search query value with this approach

```
let documents: Vec<Movie> = movies.get_documents(None, Some(55), None).await.unwrap();
```

my current way to search:

```
let results: SearchResults<Movie> = index
    .search()
    .with_query(&sometestval)
    .execute()
    .await
    .expect("Failed to execute query");
```

I tried to use arguments like `.limit()` but nothing worked. I am not sure if I overlooked something or this functionality is currently not supported by this relatively new project. If anybody has an idea I would be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, it's not called `limit()` but [`with_limit()`](https://docs.rs/meilisearch-sdk/0.4.0/meilisearch_sdk/search/struct.Query.html#method.with_limit).

```rust
let results: SearchResults<Movie> = index
    .search()
    .with_query(&sometestval)
    .with_limit(55)
    .execute()
    .await
    .expect("Failed to execute query");
```

See also ["Limit - Search Parameters | MeiliSearch Documentation v0.18"](https://docs.meilisearch.com/guides/advanced_guides/search_parameters.html#limit).